# UIWebView - white background before loading content

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiwebview

I have a question. I have a menu, when I click on it, it will load content remotely from URL via UIWebView.

When I try on simulator, before loading the content, there's a white background and then loads my HTML Page (which has dark background)

**Demo:**

[image: https://s3.amazonaws.com/quickcast/6134/84576/quickcast.gif]

You can see that white flash, when I click on "KALENDER"

How can I fix this issue?

My UIWebView looks like this:

```
        let myWebView:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height))
        myWebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://website.com/test.html")!))
        self.view.addSubview(myWebView)
```

Thank you!

Comment: have you set UIWebView background to black color or what color you wanted??

Answer (score 24):

So, what I did, is, added:

```
myWebView.opaque = false
myWebView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

and at controller, I unchecked this from "View"

[image]

Comment: You only need apply clearColor to backgroundColor and uncheck Opaque all from Storyboard !

Answer (score 3):

You cannot set background color to your webView.

You should try following steps:

**1. write following in your viewDidLoad - Setting delegate and hiding webView.**

```
webView.delegate = self

webView.hidden = YES
```

**2. Write delegate - `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` - hiding webView when loading starts.**

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView!, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest!, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -&gt; Bool {
webView.hidden = YES
return true;
}
```

**3. Write delegate - `webViewDidFinishLoad` - Show webView when loading Ends.**

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView!) {
webView.hidden = NO
print("Webview did finish load")
}
```

Hope this will help you....

Comment: Thanks for your time, but it didn't work. It's different at me.

Comment: Value of type 'WKWebView' has no member 'delegate'

Answer (score -1):

You could load your own html document, which uses the color you need.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let htmlString = "<html><body bgcolor=\"#ABCDEF\"></body></html>"
    webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
}
```

Comment: It's not working since loadHTMLString() also takes a small while to load.