# How to remove white screen coming before loading webpage in WKWebView in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

In my project I have splash screen and WKWebViewController. After splash screen redirect in WkWebViewController and open one url. But after splash screen for 2-3 sec one white screen come and then load the web page. I want to remove this white screen or change the color of that screen. My code for webpage is :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController , WKNavigationDelegate  {

@IBOutlet weak var webview: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    webview.navigationDelegate = self
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     loveredioweb()
}

func loveredioweb()  {
    let url = "URL"
    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    self.webview.load(request)
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    SVProgressHUD.show()
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
  }
}
```

Comment: it's a web view functionality we are not able to remove it but at this point, you can show a loader or a  splace screen above of weview and when webview finish loading completely than you will show the webview.

Comment: yes. we cannot able to remove it. I clear the color of webview. I got soltution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29009132/uiwebview-white-background-before-loading-content